# How to replace space with comma using sed?

Tags: regex, unix, vim, replace, sed

I would like to replace the empty space between each and every field with comma delimiter.Could someone let me know how can I do this.I tried the below command but it doesn't work.thanks.

```
My command:
:%s//,/


53 51097 310780 1
56 260 1925 1
68 51282 278770 1
77 46903 281485 1
82 475 2600 1
84 433 3395 1
96 212 1545 1
163 373819 1006375 1
204 36917 117195 1
```

Comment: Is this VIM? I don't see `sed` anywhere.

Comment: Yea it's inside vim editor.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If you are talking about `sed`, this works:

```
sed -e "s/ /,/g" < a.txt
```

In `vim`, use same regex to replace:

```
s/ /,/g
```

Comment: It does look like he's trying to use Vim here, not sed, good call

Answer (score 12):

Inside `vim`, you want to type when in normal (command) mode:

```
:%s/ /,/g
```

On the terminal prompt, you can use `sed` to perform this on a file:

```
sed -i 's/\ /,/g' input_file
```

**Note:** the `-i` option to `sed` means "in-place edit", as in that it will modify the input file.

Comment: If you are on Max OSX the `-i` option requires an argument. You can pass it an empty string if you don't desire a backup.

Comment: ^ thank you so much, spent a while trying to fix this command on a mac

Answer (score 4):

IF your data includes an arbitrary sequence of blank characters (tab, space), and you want to replace each sequence with one comma, use the following:

```
sed 's/[\t ]+/,/g' input_file
```

or

```
sed -r 's/[[:blank:]]+/,/g' input_file
```

If you want to replace sequence of space characters, which includes other characters such as carriage return and backspace, etc, then use the following:

```
sed -r 's/[[:space:]]+/,/g' input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it's not exactly what you're asking, but, for replacing a comma with a newline, this works great:

```
tr , '\n' < file
```

Comment: Nice one, I was looking for this specifically, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try the following command and it should work out for you.

```
sed "s/\s/,/g" orignalFive.csv > editedFinal.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the output on terminal then,

```
$sed 's/ /,/g' filename.txt
```

But if you want to edit the file itself *i.e.* if you want to replace space with the comma in the file then,

```
$sed -i 's/ /,/g' filename.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I just confirmed that:

```
cat file.txt | sed "s/\s/,/g"
```

successfully replaces spaces with commas in Cygwin terminals (mintty 2.9.0). None of the other samples worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

On Linux use below to test (it would replace the whitespaces with comma)

```
 sed 's/\s/,/g' /tmp/test.txt | head
```

later you can take the output into the file using below command:

```
sed 's/\s/,/g' /tmp/test.txt > /tmp/test_final.txt
```

PS: test is the file which you want to use