# How do I optimize the python code to read a batch of multiple lines rather than one line at a time?

Tags: python, csv

I have written a code that reads a **large** (>15 GB) text file and converts the data for a csv file one line at a time.

```
txt_file = fileName+".txt"
    csv_file = fileName+".csv"
    with open(txt_file, "r") as tf, open(csv_file, "w") as cf:
        for line in tf:
            cf.writelines(" ".join(line.split()).replace(' ', ','))
            cf.write("\n")
```

edit:
As for the data,
Data in input file:
abc def ghi jkl

Expected data in output file:
abc,def,ghi,jkl

I am using Python 2.7.6 in Mac OSX 10.10.3

Comment: So why not use the `csv` module instead of reinventing the CSV wheel? And with file buffers, you are already reading the file in chunks.

Comment: What is the delimiter for the input file? This looks better suited for a sed command.

Comment: Also, `" ".join(line.split()).replace(' ', ',')` is a very round-about way of saying `",".join(line.split())`...

Comment: Input file is delimited by a single space.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538772/how-to-replace-space-with-comma-using-sed

Answer (score 2):

Leave parsing and formatting CSV to the `csv` module:

```
import csv

txt_file = fileName + ".txt"
csv_file = fileName + ".csv"
with open(txt_file, "rb") as tf, open(csv_file, "wb") as cf:
    reader = csv.reader(tf, delimiter=' ')
    writer = csv.writer(cf)
    writer.writerows(reader)
```

or if you have strange quoting, treating the input file as text and manually splitting:

```
import csv

txt_file = fileName + ".txt"
csv_file = fileName + ".csv"
with open(txt_file, "rb") as tf, open(csv_file, "wb") as cf:
    writer = csv.writer(cf)
    writer.writerows(line.split() for line in tf)
```

File streams use buffers to read and write data in chunks.

Comment: I was doing this initially, but this is not working for the large file I have as specified in the question. I tested it again now.

Comment: @PiyushRoutray: define 'not working'. Perhaps if you told us more about the format you have? Are there quotes involved? You can adjust quote handling behaviour too, but you'll need to provide more details.

Comment: Not working as in I get only 0.42 GB output .csv file for around 18 GB .txt file. This is, I suspect, because of RAM limitations??. 

As for the data,
Data in input file:
abc def ghi jkl 

Expected data in output file
abc,def,ghi,jkl

Comment: @PiyushRoutray: I've processed CSV files far larger than that with the module. The `writer.writerows()` iterates lazily over the reader, it'll never process more than one row at a time; the rest is file buffers.

Comment: @PiyushRoutray: so what Python version are you using, and what OS are you running this on?

Comment: python 2.7.6  
Mac OS X 10.10.3

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not technically answering your question, but if you are able to process the files before your python script, I believe using sed would be the fastest way to do this. Considering your large file sizes, I think it is worth the non python related suggestion.

[How to replace space with comma using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538772/how-to-replace-space-with-comma-using-sed)

You can do this via command line before starting your python script, or even invoke it within your script using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do it is this.

```
with open("file.json", "r") as r, open("write.csv", "a") as w:
    lines = []
    for l in r:
        #Process l
        if len(lines) < 1000000: #Only uses 54mb of RAM so I hear
            lines.append(l)
        else:
            w.writelines(lines)
            del lines[:]
```