# Adding new line in R

Tags: r

I need to add a new line after the `;`. My data looks like this:

```
(1,60112_486_100_xxx_BS);(1,1_486_100_yyy_TE);
```

I need:

```
(1,60112_486_100_xxx_BS);
(1,1_486_100_yyy_TE);
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: please `dput(...)` your data...

Answer (score 1):

A command line tool like sed ([How to replace space with comma using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538772/how-to-replace-space-with-comma-using-sed)) seems more suitable for this job.
If you really want to to this in R, you could use e.g. `yourData <- readLines(...)` and `gsub(");",");\n",yourData)`